# How to replace Spartacus desktop icon?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, spartacus-storefront

When we navigate to our new SAP Spartacus web site, due to the PWA nature of the app, we can choose to install the application on the device we're using. When installing the app happens, the default icon provided in the Spartacus code is used, and I can see in the Spartacus code where it looks like this file came from:

..\js-storefront\mymobilestore\src\assets\icons

The name of the file from the Spartacus code that's used is 'icon-128x128.png', and I can see this file being referenced in the following file:

..\js-storefront\mymobilestore\src\manifest.webmanifest

Here's is where I found the reference to this icon file:

"icons": [
{
"src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
"sizes": "72x72",
"type": "image/png",
"purpose": "maskable any"
},
{
"src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
"sizes": "96x96",
"type": "image/png",
"purpose": "maskable any"
},
**{
"src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
"sizes": "128x128",
"type": "image/png",
"purpose": "maskable any"
},**
{
"src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
"sizes": "144x144",
"type": "image/png",
"purpose": "maskable any"
},

We want to replace the default icon used when you install Spartacus on your device with a custom one that reflects our company. I figured that it would be as easy as simply putting our custom icon in the ..\js-storefront\mymobilestore\src\assets\icons folder and then update the area of the manifest.webmanifest file that references this file. Unfortunately, this is not working for me as the original Spartacus icon is still being used.

Can anyone share with me what I'm doing wrong? How do I replace the default icon used when installing our Spartacus app on a device?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem myself. It turns out that the icon being installed on my desktop was not the icon in the source code that I thought it was.

When initially working on replacing the icon file, I had found the actual file being used as the desktop icon, and I could see the size of that file was 128x128. I naturally assumed that all I needed to do was replace the icon-128x128.png file in source code and that would do the trick, but it did not.

I ended up replacing every one of the out of the box icons with a different icon of the appropriate size, and I updated the manifest.webmanifest file with the names of each of the new files. After then deploying my code and installing Spartacus on my desktop, I could see the 72x72 size icon file was being used.

I found the following site very useful when it came to describing installation icons for PWA applications:
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/app-icons-in-a-pwa-8fb775207ad7

I hope this helps someone else!